# Unexpected interruption announcing John F. Kennedy's birthday

Tags: iphone, ios, alert

[image: Unexpected alert]

*(May 28, 2015, 0900 USPacific/LosAngeles)*

I did not configure this alert.

Why was I interrupted for John F. Kennedy's upcoming birthday?

Comment: Are you subscribed to any additional calendars?  I am subscribed to the "U.S. Holidays" calendar and I received the same alert about an hour ago.  From within the Calendars app, click on Calendars at the bottom.

Comment: If you want to avoid interruption during important recordings, setting the phone to "Do not disturb" and/or Airplane mode might help.

Comment: FYI, I gave you a down vote for ranting. One is the Bday pop up, which is fine to ask. The other is the ranting about been interrupted. You specifically asked for it to be interrupted (called notification/alerts). If you do not want to be interrupted turn it off. Airplane mode or the Do not Disturb.

Comment: @PatrickMcMahon upon further investigation, I do happen to be subscribed to these alerts, and allow notifications, and Calendars is set to Alert in Notification Center, so indeed the lion's share of this makes sense now. (I thought it may have been an aftershock of the Apple/U2 auto-omni-download album fiasco). Left in question now is whether there exists a way to discriminate between my mission-critical, modal-preferred alerts that I designate, and "nice-to-know" here-and-gone minimally-invasive banners. Can Notification Center support such behaviour currently?

Comment: Please either rephrase your question accordingly or create a new one. Comments are primarily used for clarifications, not for follow-up questions or lengthy discussions.

Answer (score 3):

This alert does not show up unless you have opted in to iCloud calendars that include that alert.

You are most likely subscribed to a US holidays calender.  Open Calenders, then click "Calenders" just above the home button.  Select that calender using the "i" button on the right and you will be able to turn off alerts for events originating from that calendar.

If I guessed incorrectly, select options from the dialog shown and you will be able to determine which calendar has that specific alert and change the settings you selected or potentially unsubscribe from that calendar entirely.